# Microsoft Graph user endpoint does not return otherMails-property

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get the property `otherMails` when searching for users like this:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(givenName, 'anna')&$select=displayName,otherMails`

However, the response does not contain `otherMails`:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(displayName,otherMails)",
    "value": [
        {
            "displayName": "Anna Karenina",
            "otherMails": []
        }
    ]
}
```

The user has the property set in Azure AD:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? According to the documentation, this property should be returned on `$select`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0

> A list of additional email addresses for the user; for example: ["bob@contoso.com", "Robert@fabrikam.com"].
> NOTE: This property cannot contain accent characters.
> Returned only on $select. Supports $filter (eq, not, ge, le, in, startsWith).

Comment: What type of User.* permissions did you add to your app?

Comment: Would proxyAddresses work for you instead?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @user2250152, I only had `User.ReadBasic.All` permission, but with `User.Read.All` it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be able to read `otherMails` you need to add `User.Read.All` permission which allows the app to read the full set of profile properties, reports, and managers of other users.

Resources:

[User permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference?msclkid=7612d1fbb02a11ecaaa0001a382cbe91#user-permissions)